# Angular Menu Display is Incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am learning angular, I have created a material menu that is not displaying correctly. Based on the code i have added it should display the same as this image.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<button mat-button> Products</button>



<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" overlapTrigger="true">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I also have some images being displayed in my html and I get the following output:

[image]

I am not getting any console errors, these are my imports

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import {  BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { 
  MatMenuModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatListModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    ProductComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

First question is why are my options gray? and second question is why is my overlay not working properly? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your HTML. See this working [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txxhsx) with the HTML you provided. Are you getting any console errors, did you import the required material modules? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Narm I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Based off the code you've provided, your HTML is fine and it appears you have included the required material modules. Given your issue revolves around styles my assumption is you're not correctly importing Angular Material Styles in your project.

You many just need to add a theme to your applications main **styles.css** file. Include the following code at the top of your **styles.css* file and see if that resolves your issue.

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Comment: thanks , this works for me, but why this import is required , last time withod this my menu was working